# Height Map: how to deleted unwanted faces?

Tags: height-map

SupFolks!

I applied a height map to a plane and was wondering if there's an easier way that I can delete faces circle in red w/o doing it by hand.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
Heightmap
[image]
Unwanted faces circled in red

Comment: Did you try going to a side Ortho view and selecting all the vertices at z=0?

Comment: So I hit Numpad 5>3, but I don't know how to select vertices on particular axis.

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to say "select all at this axis." I just meant from that side view, use the 'B' key and draw the select rectangle around close to the axis.

Comment: If I select edges, it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

for 2.79 :in Edit Mode, hit numpad 5 to go to ortho view and hit either numpad 1 or 3 to get to perfect sideview then hit CTRL+tab and hit E to make Edge Selection then hit B to start the box selection tool hit X and select faces to deleted unwanted faces